# Как закрепить Floating Action Button к выдвигающейся панели

Tags: java, android, material-design

Хочу реализовать функциональность, которая есть в приложении Google Map под Android. Когда вы "кликаете" на поставленном маркере на карте снизу выдвигается панель с информацией.

В отличие от приложения, который написал Google мне не нужно после этого его "тянуть" что бы нижняя панель "развернулась" на весь экран. Данная панель должна быть фиксированной высоты. Данную проблему я решил.

Но теперь мне нужно закрепить на этой панели Floating Action Button. Как показано на рисунке ниже:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

activity_main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">
        android:translationY="100dp"
    </FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

fragment1.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#FFF">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Panel"
        android:textColor="#0000DD"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:padding="5dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Fragment1.java:

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {
    public static final String TAG = "FRAGMENT1";
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1, container, false);
    }
}
```

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Fragment1 fragment1;
    private FragmentManager fragmentManager;
    private FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragment1 = new Fragment1();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            if (fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(Fragment1.TAG) == null) {
                fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_bottom, R.anim.slide_out_bottom);
                fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.container, fragment1, Fragment1.TAG);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
            } else {
                fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_bottom, R.anim.slide_out_bottom);
                fragmentTransaction.remove(fragment1);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
            }
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Буду благодарен за любые идеи и решения. Приложение должно работать с версии 4.0.3.